# 2 nodes separated physically in a distributed cache using Infinispan

Tags: tcp, nodes, distributed-caching, infinispan, jgroups

I need to implement a distributed Cache. For this I'm trying with Infinispan.

I have 2 nodes, that are separated physically. Each node is located in a Server, and the 2 servers can ping each other successfully.

In the configuration file "jgroups-tcp.xml" (JGroups), for configuring the cluster, I did the following :

```
<TCP
        bind_addr="${jgroups.tcp.address:XX.XX.AA.AA}"
        bind_port="${jgroups.tcp.port:7800}"

//...
/>


<TCPPING timeout="3000"
      initial_hosts="XX.XX.AA.AA[7800],XX.XX.BB.BB[7801]"
      port_range="5"
      num_initial_members="2"
      ergonomics="false"
/>
```

And I commented the element .

Running the application with this configuration works in the machine whose IP is `XX.XX.AA.AA`, but it doesn't for the other machine `XX.XX.BB.BB`, and I get this error :

org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: java.net.BindException: [TCP] /XX.XX.AA.AA is not a valid address on any local network interface.

For information, for the moment, I'm creating the nodes from a static main method. So I don't think that I would need to involve JBosss configurations...

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

On the BB node, you have to setup bind_addr `XX.XX.BB.BB` - I assume that you have done that, although you don't mention two configurations. But, probably, you've made some mistake.

If you don't want to keep two configuration files, you can set `bind_addr="${jgroups.tcp.address}"` and then use `-Djgroup.tcp.address=XX.XX.AA.AA` (`BB.BB`, respectively) on the command line when starting JVMs.